# Why is this console.log() failing?

Tags: javascript, html, css, console.log

I am creating Rock Paper Scissors for a class, and I'm trying to get it to log the winner in the console, but nothing happens when the button is pressed. I'm not sure why. Is there anything obviously wrong with my code here?

```js
let playGame = function() {
  let userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
  let computerChoice = Math.random();

  let userWins = 0;
  let compWins = 0;

  if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
  } else if (computerChoice <= 0.67 && computerChoice >= 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
  } else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
  }

  let compare = function(choice1, choice2) {

    if (choice1 === choice2) {
      console.log("The result is a tie!");
    } else if (choice1 === "rock") {
      if (choice2 === "scissors") {
        console.log("User wins!");
      } else {
        console.log("Computer wins!");
      }
    } else if (choice1 === "paper") {
      if (choice2 === "rock") {
        console.log("User wins!");
      } else {
        console.log("Computer wins!");
      }
    } else if (choice1 === "scissors") {
      if (choice2 === "paper") {
        console.log("User wins!");
      } else {
        console.log("Computer wins!");
      }
    }
  };

  compare(userChoice, computerChoice);
}
```

```html
<button class="playGame" onclick="playGame()">Play!</button>
```

Comment: Can you explain more about what is wrong? What do you expect? What are you getting? Do you have console errors?

Comment: Look in your web console, there's almost certainly an error there explaining why nothing appears to happen.

Comment: Nothing is showing up in the console, that's my big issue. If I parse playGame() into the console itself, all it says is `undefined` but doesn't give an error...

Comment: I copied your code into a Stack Snippet (the `[<>]` toolbar button) and it works. If, by some chance, you happened to be doing this on jsFiddle, you were probably running into jsFiddle's very surprising default of wrapping all your JavaScript code in a `window.onload = function() { };` wrapper. The function called from `onxyz` attributes must be a global, which it won't be if it's inline jsFiddle's bizarre default.

Comment: `let playGame = function()` how it can worked in real world?

Comment: @anete.anetes: What do you mean? That's perfectly valid code.

Comment: Side note: It's not the problem, but the `&& computerChoice >= 0.34` in `} else if (computerChoice <= 0.67 && computerChoice >= 0.34) {` is completely unnecessary. You've already ruled out that possibility with the previous `if`, and you've used `else` to introduce the new one.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder what if `playGame` inside context like `$(document).ready(~here~)` ?

Comment: @anete.anetes: Same problem as the jsFiddle thing I mentioned above. But the OP would be getting an error message and says he/she isn't. (There's also nothing whatsoever to suggest the OP is using jQuery.)

Comment: Nope, can't use JQuery for the assignment unfortunately.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It wasn't on JSFiddle, but it is local if that makes a difference. Should I upload it and try it then?

Comment: @BJohnson: No, for this particular purpose it doesn't matter if it's a local file. But since the code above does work, something is different between your local file and the code in the question, so I suggest reading through [mcve] and posting the complete, but minimal, file in a code block in the question. Something is different.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Hm. I copied it right from the file, but I will look. Thanks

Comment: Stupid question but are you typing in rock, paper or scissors correctly?  They will be case sensitive and nothing would happen if you don't type one of the three in or spell them wrong / have the incorrect case

Comment: @Pete You're a genius Pete. I can't believe I'm that stupid haha. I guess not having slept in 36 hours will do that to you. Thank you a ton man.

Comment: You're welcome - if all else fails come at it from an end user point of view!